# What is this game that appear in the right of all pages of MSE? (UNIKONG)

Tags: support

What is this game that appear in all pages of MSE from yesterday?!
[image: UNIKONG]

It happens only for me or it happens for all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the April Fools' joke ran by SE over the entire network.

The game is not bad, too bad there are only three levels.

Comment: :) I played this game until level 6 !

Comment: I find many question about this at meta.stackoverflow  like : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320268/why-do-we-start-with-0-rep-in-unikong

Comment: Actually, it seems that the game becomes harder and harder when you advance.

Comment: @wythagoras really? Great idea ;-)